# Ignore Entity while sorting with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to sort the output of a list of names. But we've added "&lt" entities to the data to identify italics that needs to be added to the data later.

Is there a way to tell the XSLT to ignore the entities and sort only alpha letters and numbers? The only thing we really need it to ignore is the "&lt" entity itself.

Any idea?

Here's the actual expression I'm using (Let me know if you need the entire XSL):

```
 <xsl:template match="index">
 <index><xsl:for-each select="indexitem">
 <xsl:sort select="name"/>
 <indexitem>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/> 
 <xsl:apply-templates select="scott"/>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="searchterm"/>
 </indexitem></xsl:for-each></index>
 </xsl:template>
```

Sample XML:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><index>
 <indexitem><name>&lt;Interphil&gt; 76</name><scott>(1632)</scott>;  <searchterm>Interphil 76</searchterm></indexitem>
 <indexitem><name>Baldwin, James</name><scott>(3871)</scott>; <searchterm>James Baldwin</searchterm></indexitem>
 <indexitem><name>Benny, Jack</name><scott>(2564)</scott>; <searchterm>Jack Benny</searchterm></indexitem>
 </index>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably achieve what you want by using the `translate` function to remove the `&lt;` entity

```
<xsl:for-each select="indexitem">
    <xsl:sort select="translate(name, '&lt;', '')"/>
```

Note that this will remove the entity wherever it occurs in the string, not just the start.

Comment: That worked fine. It did not replace the entity. The list sorts properly without bothering the entity. Thanks!

Comment: Using translate inside the sort command does not remove the entity from the output, only the sort routine. I've used it in the past to swap certain characters. I forgot about it since I haven't used it in a while.

Comment: To remove the entity from the output, you would need to have a template matching `name` and use translate in there too.

Comment: I don't need or want to remove the entity, I just want to remove it from the search function. This current solution works exactly the way I want it to.